# Expanding doorway - can this be done?

Tags: renovation, building

I’m hoping to get an idea of what options are to incorporate a French/sliding door into my kitchen living space.

We currently have a doorway in kitchen that leads to back door entryway and under stair cupboard opposite back door. I would like to sort of expand rear of kitchen to include this entryway as part of kitchen (so removing doorway, cutting into under stair cupboard space so that the back door can be replaced with a wider French or sliding door (with transom above) to improve light and provide direct access to rear patio.

The wall that would be partially taken out runs from front to back of our house and is presumably supporting stairs (but admittedly I have no idea)- and will of course check this.

Assuming it’s a supporting wall, is there a way to make this work without it looking terrible. I’m finding it hard to picture how it could work.

It is probably relevant that there’s an existing rsj through the room from previously knocking through two rooms.

I appreciate I’ve probably not explained myself very well so have included very rough and not to scale of the current layout and what I have in mind.

Thanks[image]

---

This is what I have in mind. Will also try to post of current view but having difficulty with this at the moment [image]

---

Here is current view from kitchen so basically I’d like to widen the back door without it looking like the French doors are straddled between two rooms, so would like to incorporate the entryway to back door as part of the kitchen. [image]

Comment: Got any idea which way your joists run?